# How can I force the gnome clock in the top menu bar to update?

Tags: gnome, clock

I am running Ubuntu 13.10.

When I use `sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov` to update my system time, I observe that the `date` command returns the correct time, but the gnome clock in the top menu bar on the right does not update and it seems to be frozen in time.

How can I force it to update without logging out and logging back in?